# Debian bookworm - Is VDPAU really enabled

Tags: debian, amdgpu, vdpau

New install of Debian bookworm on a system featuring an AMD Radeon RX 6600 using the amdgpu driver. I installed vdpauinfo (`sudo apt install vdpauinfo`) and found a problem  that is discussed in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hardware_video_acceleration#Configuring_VDPAU).

```bash
> vdpauinfo
display: :0   screen: 0
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error creating VDPAU device: 1
```

I'm surprised this isn't configured out of the box with bookworm (and I'm new to Debian).  Am I missing something, or do I need to set the `VDPAU_DRIVER` environment variable (which is unset out of the box in my distro)?

Comment: that's almost the exact message I get when using xRDP rather than being on the computer itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to set the `VDPAU_DRIVER` environment variable. Apparently the correct value might be `radeonsi`, `r600` or `r300`, depending on the model of your AMD Radeon card.

(I have no experience of using AMD GPUs with modern Linuxes, since I've been a long-time NVidia user.)

In Debian, the location of the VDPAU driver library files is not `/usr/lib/vdpau` as described in the Arch wiki, but `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did set the environment variable (add `VDPAU=radeonsi`) to `/etc/environment` and now `vdpauinfo` returns the expected information ... and a seg fault at the end.  Perhaps I should leave good enough alone and depend only on VA-API.